# how to get url from setting.xml via SettingsBuildingResult event

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve the server URL from the Maven settings file. However, the URL is not directly available in the Server class of Maven. I've tried accessing the Server objects from the settings but couldn't find a method to retrieve the URL. I've checked the official documentation [link to the documentation] but it doesn't provide a direct solution for this.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    Settings settings = settingsBuildingResult.getEffectiveSettings();
    
    for (Server server : settings.getServers()) {
        if (serverId.equals(server.getId())) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

I need to access the server URL to perform further operations. Is there any workaround or alternative approach to retrieve the server URL from the Maven settings when it's not available in the Server class? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Server Class
https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-settings/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Server.html

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve the server URL from Maven settings?

Comment: I need to retrive server/repositories url based on that, I need supply additional headers for only some repo,

Comment: Additional headers? Sounds a bit strange ... also I would recommend to use a repository manager which could handle such things... furthermore the question is if you have those URL's and when should be a change happen? Are you change the source code of Maven? If so I would recommend to use more recent versions of Maven etc. Or are you workgin within a plugin? Can you give much more detailed information what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am working on the maven extension, I want to add a few HTTP headers to specify repository calls